# Sitecore 9.2 Forms with Salesforce 3.0 CRM Connector - Sitecore Form data post to create Lead in Salesforce

Tags: sitecore-forms, salesforce-connect

Environment: 
Sitecore 9.2
Salesforce 3.0 CRM Connector

My requirement is to create Sitecore Form for simple inquiry to capture details like Name, Email, Phone and Message and send to Salesforce to create Lead.

I have referred to the below article for created submit action but is there any better way to create lead in sitecore with sitecore form data?

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-submit-action.html

Any help greatly appreciated..!!

Answer (score 1):

Submit action will only save the facet in XDB but after that you will need to sync that facet with Salesforce.

You will need to install and configure Sitecore Salesforce connector to sync XDB and Salesforce.

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Salesforce_Connect/3x/Sitecore_Connect_for_Salesforce_CRM_300.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have already setup the xdb and salesforce connectors. I see all the pipelines in place. How to we make sure the data flows between two ends. I don't even have the xDB in place yet. Can you give more details around how to handle the sitecore form data to push to salesforce?